# The chat search doesn't find my name in the transcript

Tags: bug, chat, search

By accident I stumbled into [a chat message referring to me](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/10?m=6574489#6574489). I am pretty sure I wasn't notified of that message, but I am not 100%, I'll let this one drop now. Wondering what else I might have missed, I [searched for my name in the chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/search?q=@sbi&Room=10&sort=newest), and was surprised that the search wouldn't bring up the message I had found by accident.

I think this is a (yet another) bug in the chat search.

Comment: Hi sbi, if you look back in your inbox to every message you received on December 6th, do you see that message? At the bottom of the inbox, you can click "more inbox messages" to see beyond what shows up in the global inbox at the top of the page...

Comment: @jmort253: A search finds no "sbi's" string in my inbox, and it goes back to Dec, 4th.